# JavaScript - Protocol handlers registered but, reading fails from windows registry

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, protocols, moniker

I did following:

1) In Windows 7: Under registry: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PROTOCOLS\Handler`
I have my custom protocol calls: `stackoverflow` (copied similar way in registry like other protocols `mailto` or `ftp` etc)

[Followed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/836956/285594)

2) Open in IE the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/L528u/

```
<a href="stackoverflow:talking" id="link1">CLICK IT</a>
<button onclick="alert(document.getElementById('link1').protocolLong);">CHECK - IF - Protocol available or not</button>
```

3) when click the button from IE to detect the protocol: stackoverflow it fails

I get always alert box: "Unknown protocol" but when i try to detect protocols like: ftp, mailto it works

```
<a href="ftp:talking" id="link1">CLICK IT</a>
<button onclick="alert(document.getElementById('link1').protocolLong);">CHECK - IF - Protocol available or not</button>
```

Question: Can anyone please tell me what is missing in registry entry for to activate the new protocol? "stackoverflow" (where ftp, mailto works but not stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer only surfaces built-in protocols via protocolLong. There isn't anything you can put in the registry to allow web-based detection of Application Protocols.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266527(v=vs.85).aspx - Can someone use this to manually make a Protocol handler and then via IE reuse that custom protocol? if yes possible to show a manual demo cause Google Hangout in Windows does it perfectly and there is no resource available how its done.

Comment: The "protocol handlers" documentation you're showing is related to the search indexer. IE supports Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol implementations (see the top of http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/07/14/url-protocols-application-protocols-and-asynchronous-pluggable-protocols-oh-my.aspx) but these are extremely complicated and only used by IE. They also are not detectable using protocolLong.

Comment: This is the way i made it works for your information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24675548/innosetup-is-there-any-way-to-manually-create-cookie-for-internet-explorer

Comment: Setting a cookie only works so long as the user hasn't cleared their cookies, and the answer you cite won't work properly if the target is running in Protected Mode.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 10 (and later) on Windows 8 (and later, note that Windows 7 is not included! See [msLaunchUri not available in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23396303/mslaunchuri-not-available-in-ie11)) implements a new method with a success and an error callback parameters that can assist in protocol handler invoking situations - `navigator.msLaunchUri(uri, successCallback, noHandlerCallback)`.
For details, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj154912(v=vs.85).aspx